# MongoDB results that partially satisfy criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to write a query in Node so that mongo will tell me if there are results which partially satisfy search criteria.

If data inside the DB is organized like this:

```
{
    param1: String,
    param2: String,
    param3: String
}
```

Furthermore, param2 is unique for every entry.

And the query would be something like this

```
findOne({param1:'str1', param2:'str2', param3:'str3'}, function(...){});
```

Essentially, I need a query that will tell me if the returned result(s) completely or partially satisfy search criteria. If the result satisfies param1 and param2 but NOT param3 a message or an error is returned alongside the resulting object. Is this possible in mongoDB? findOne() is just an example, it doesn't necessarily have to be a findOne() query, or a single query if it is not possible. If so, how can it be done using the least amount of queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to return objects from the mongo collection and to attach information to each object which condition it satisfies and which not. Suppose that we have a mongodb collection person which objects have fields firstName, lastName and birthYear. We can use this aggregation

```
db.person.aggregate([

    {
        $project : {
            firstName : "$firstName",
            lastName : "$lastName",
            birthYear : "$birthYear",
            matchCondition1 : { $cond: { if: { $eq : [ "$firstName" , "Novak" ] }, then: 200 , else: 100 }} ,
            matchCondition2 : { $cond: { if: { $eq : [ "$lastName" , "Djokovic" ] }, then: 20 , else: 10 }} ,
            matchCondition3 : { $cond: { if: { $eq : [ "$birthYear" , 1987 ] }, then: 2 , else: 1 }}
        }
    }, 
    {
        $project : {
            firstName : "$firstName",
            lastName : "$lastName",
            birthYear : "$birthYear",
            matchConditions : { $sum : [ "$matchCondition1", "$matchCondition2", "$matchCondition3" ] }
        }
    }

]);
```

Result would look like:
{ firstName : "Novak", lastName : "Djokovic", birthYear : "1987", matchConditions : 222 }

{ firstName : "Novak", lastName : "Petrovic", birthYear : "1987", matchConditions : 212 }

{ firstName : "Novak", lastName : "Petrovic", birthYear : "1989", matchConditions : 211 }

{ firstName : "Roger", lastName : "Federer", birthYear : "1981", matchConditions : 111 }

Then from the matchCondition field you can get the information for each condition does object satisfies it. I hopes this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ne` for a field not to match a value.

The following will query with the params  `{'param1':'value1','param2':'value2','param3' : {'$ne' : 'value3'}}`, matching `value1` for `param1`, `value2` for `param2` and **not** `value3` for `param3` :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDB';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

  assert.equal(null, err);

  db.collection('yourCollection').find({'param1':'value1','param2':'value2','param3' : {'$ne' : 'value3'}}).toArray(function(err, doc) {

      assert.equal(null, err);

      if (doc != null) {
         console.log(doc);
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `$or` operator

```
findOne($or: [{param1:'str1'}, {param2:'str2'}, {param3:'str3'}], function(...){});
```

and then in the result, you would write your own custom logic to determine which parameters were not found.